# Validate Boolean Query - java

Tags: java

I need the java code snippet for the below logic:

Following is a string and I need to validate the string based on the below condition :

"**100** or **200** and **345** not **550** " - Valid string

"**abc** or **200** and **345** SAME **** 550 " - Not a Valid String

1 . the operands(eg 100,200 ..) should be positive numbers
2 . the operator should be and/or/not

Thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [regular expressions](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/essential/regex/) in Java to do that.

Yo can try this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String test = "1212 and 120 or 390";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^\\d+(\\s(and|or|not)\\s\\d+)*$");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(test);
    if (m.matches()) {
        System.out.println("Valid!");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Invalid.");
    }
}
```

Comment: Write a little parser. Should not be difficult to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

A regex is probably easiest method:

```
"100 or 200 and 345 not 550".matches("^[1-9][0-9]*( (or|and|not) [1-9][0-9]*)*$")
```